# Hide or rename a NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net

Is there anyway I can hide package name or rename it or put it another custom created package and call it.
I'm making a little application but I don't want the Package names to be show as their DLL files matching the name of package are also build with the solution in visual studio.
Is that possible? I'm new to C# , under php I could change the class name and file name as well and call it in another file but I don't know if its possible in C#

Answer (score 0):

you can right-click the project in Visual Studio solution explorer. then change the assembly name. It will generate the DLL with the custom name.

[image]

Comment: I think i mean the references or packages downloaded from nuget  not the assembly names because there isn't option there to rename it and the name the is read only you can't modify it [link]https://prnt.sc/vTu7I8zkJWN2